# Does AQE physically duplicates data on one side of a join when tackling data skew on the other side?

Tags: apache-spark

This figure is extracted from the Databricks' blog article [*"Adaptive Query Execution: Speeding Up Spark SQL at Runtime"*](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/05/29/adaptive-query-execution-speeding-up-spark-sql-at-runtime.html) in the *"Dynamically optimizing skew joins"* section:

[image]

The "Duplicate B0" label is confusing to me and it is not explicited in the article. Is there any replication of the shuffle files (corresponding to the partition *B0*) involved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no data replication**, the only additional cost is that the *B0* partition has to be fetched several times (1 time for each split of the *A0* skewed partition), hence increasing the network cost of the job.

---

***Source:***
The [doc associated with the issue *"[SPARK-29544] Optimize skewed join at runtime with new Adaptive Execution"*](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NkXN-ck8jUOS0COz3f8LUW5xzF8j9HFjoZXWGGX2HAg) that does not mention any replication and only warns with:

> This approach will introduce the additional cost by reading N times about the partition 0 of table A. However the benefit of handing the skew join may be more than the cost.